# I need to integrate checkout.com with apple payment like strip in react native?

Tags: react-native, checkout, applepay

*Need to integrate apple payment* with checkout payment gateway in react native if anyone can help really appreciate it and buy him a coffee thanks.

Comment: Did you be able to add ApplePay using chacckout.com?

Answer (score 0):

Have the knowledge ApplePay as a payment option via Checkout.com PG

The steps are quite simple

1. Make an eligibility call to Apple client
2. Get a token from Apple pay server
3. Trigger the Apple pay payment sheet for biometric/face recognition authentication
4. Get the response params from ApplePay client
5. Make a Authorisation API call to the PG
6. Redirect the user to the Thank you page

Please share some specifics on where you are stuck and I can help out.